# R: Creating new rows from column values

Tags: r

I have a messy dataset with multiple values in a single column, separated by a `;`. I'd like to create new rows for each separate value in the column. For example:

```
    ID    Date        Dx
    1     10/1/15     anemia ; headache ;
    2     10/1/15     migraine ; anemia ;
    3     10/2/15     diabetes ;
```

would return:

```
    ID    Date      Dx
    1     10/1/15   anemia
    1     10/1/15   headache
    2     10/1/15   migraine
    2     10/1/15   anemia
    3     10/2/15   diabetes
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm a novice R user and this has me stumped.

Comment: Thanks Vincent for the aesthetic modification

Comment: Thank you for all the suggestions and time. I apologize if this is a duplicate post.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `unnest` function from `tidyr` package:

```
library(data.table); library(tidyr);
setDT(df)[, Dx := list(strsplit(as.character(Dx), ";"))]
df %>% unnest(Dx)

Source: local data frame [5 x 3]

     ID    Date       Dx
  (int)  (fctr)    (chr)
1     1 10/1/15   anemia
2     1 10/1/15 headache
3     2 10/1/15 migraine
4     2 10/1/15   anemia
5     3 10/2/15 diabetes
```

Comment: `unnest` fits more neatly in a dplyr chain, as that was what it was designed for: `df %>% mutate(Dx = strsplit(Dx, '[ ;]+')) %>% unnest(Dx)`. The data.table equivalent would be `setDT(df)[, .(ID, Date, Dx = strsplit(Dx, '[ ;]+'))][, .(Dx = unlist(Dx)), by = .(ID, Date)]`

Answer (score 3):

Or using `?cSplit()` from `splitstackshape` package:

```
library(splitstackshape)

cSplit(df, 3, ";", "long")
#   ID    Date       Dx
#1:  1 10/1/15   anemia
#2:  1 10/1/15 headache
#3:  2 10/1/15 migraine
#4:  2 10/1/15   anemia
#5:  3 10/2/15 diabetes
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:3, Date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("10/1/15", 
"10/2/15"), class = "factor"), Dx = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("anemia ; headache ;", 
"diabetes ;", "migraine ; anemia ;"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("ID", 
"Date", "Dx"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use any additional package for this trivial task. Just use this:

```
data.frame(ID = rep(mydf$ID, sapply(strsplit(mydf$DX, split = ";"), length)),Date= rep(mydf$Date, sapply(strsplit(mydf$DX, split = ";"), length)), DX = unlist(strsplit(mydf$DX, split = ";")))
```

Answer (score -1):

Using base R you coult try:

```
do.call(rbind, apply(df, 1, function(x) data.frame(ID = x[1], 
    Date = x[2], Dx = strsplit(x[3], ";"), row.names = NULL)))
  ID    Date       Dx
1  1 10/1/15   anemia
2  1 10/1/15 headache
3  2 10/1/15 migraine
4  2 10/1/15   anemia
5  3 10/2/15 diabetes
```

Comment: `apply` converts to a matrix, so you'll lose all kinds of info by doing this